# pop To View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I am new to coding objective-C and am trying to use pop to `viewController`. To do this when a button is tapped i use

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:(what goes here) animated:YES];
```

I know its a `UIViewController*` that goes there but I am wondering where do I declare this and what code would I use to declare it.

My basic storyboard is I have 4 view controller A,B,C,D and A is the root which pushed to B which pushes to C which pushes to D, my button is on D and I am trying to pop back to B. The object at index method won't work because its doesn't always go `A->B->C->D` sometimes it goes `A->C->B->D` so

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

So that doesn't work.

Thanks for the help in advance. Sorry if this question is too basic.

Comment: Is your question about pushing, popping, or how to make a view controller?

Comment: If view controller B is in the navigation stack the popToViewController is the right method. You either need to keep a reference to view controller B, say as a property of your app delegate or you can iterate through the navigation controllers viewcontrollerwithrestorationidentifier array to identify the reference you need - perhaps using isMemberOf class method

Comment: If you have a storyboard, you should not be calling `pushViewController` at all. You should be using a push segue.

Comment: @MJN it is about popping sorry about that typo, how would I go about save it in the app delegate as a property? how do I save a reference of it? thanks

Comment: If you've made a typo, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I don't find this as a basic question, even I got struck in such a situation. But I found a good solution by using “Mediator Design pattern” and develop my custom UINavigationController as a coordinator by  combining the method:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and maintaining my own navigation stack.

A coordinator (your custom UINavigationController)  has to have the control over your navigation, if your are having unpredictable way of navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to find the desired view controller to pop to.

```
-(IBAction)popToDesiredViewController:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *desiredVC = nil;

    // LOOK AT ALL VIEW CONTROLLERS IN NAVIGATION CONTROLLER
    for (UIViewController *oneVC in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

        // CHECK IF THIS IS THE VIEW CONTROLLER YOU WANT
        // change this to your logic
        BOOL foundDesiredVC = [oneVC isKindOfClass: [SignInVC class]]; 

        if (foundDesiredVC) {
            desiredVC = oneVC;
            break;
        }
    }

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:desiredVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hey when I use that in the button pressed method I get this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'" and sorry about the typo

Comment: Is the desired VC nil every time that happens? If so you'll want to wrap the pop method in an if statement that only fires when the `desiredVC` exists.

Comment: I still get the error if I am logging out a user when the button is pushed and then loging them back in could that affect the stack, I would think it would because the view has been loaded??